# no matching constructors for initialization Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing an Assignment on one of my Programming modules and im a bit stuck.

I keep getting the Error no Matching Constructors for initialization whenever i create an object of a certian class.

There might be some other errors to, im still busy with the setup of everything.  Is my classes setup correctly?

SavingsAccount.h

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#include "transaction.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QDate>
class SavingsAccount
{
public:

    SavingsAccount (QString name, QString num);
    ~SavingsAccount();

    QList<Transaction> addTransaction(Transaction T);
    double totalTransactionCost();
    QString frequentTransactionType();
    QList<Transaction> transactionsOnAdate(QDate date);
    QString toString();

private:
    QString m_CustomerName;
    QString m_AccountNumber;
    QList<Transaction> m_TransactionList;
};

#endif // SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
```

SavingsAccount.cpp

```
#include "savingsaccount.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(QString name, QString num){
     m_CustomerName = name;
     m_AccountNumber = num;
}

SavingsAccount::~SavingsAccount(){

}

QList<Transaction> SavingsAccount::addTransaction(Transaction t){

}

QString SavingsAccount::frequentTransactionType(){

}

QString SavingsAccount::toString(){

}

double SavingsAccount::totalTransactionCost(){

}

QList<Transaction> SavingsAccount::transactionsOnAdate(QDate date){

}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "transaction.h"
#include "savingsaccount.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    string accName;
    int accNum;

    cout << "Enter Account Name: "<< endl;
    cin >> accName;
    cout<<"Enter Account Number: " <<endl;
    cin >> accNum;
    SavingsAccount accholder1(accName,accNum);


    return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks so much. Im really strugling with this subject so dont laugh ;-)

Comment: Post how you're creating those objects.

Comment: Nobody is going to laugh. Offtopic: you don't need to include QString and QList in your cpp file, they are already included via savingsaccount.h.

Comment: I Added Main.cpp, Sorry, forgot about that file.

Comment: You are creating `string` objects but the class requests `QString` objects. You can use one of the the two but you have to decide which one

Comment: You are passing a string and a number to SavingsAccount accholder1(accName,accNum); but the constructor is expecting 2 QStrings but this should not even compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the object with a `std::string`, but your constructor is expecting a `QString`. As of `Qt 4` (don't know if `Qt 5` allows this), there's no implicit conversion from a `std::string` to `QString`.

Either pass a pointer to a null-terminated char array:

```
SavingsAccount accholder1(accName.c_str(), accNum);
```

or use directly a `QString` to read the account name.

**EDIT:** I've just noticed that your constructor expects 2 `QStrings`, yet you're passing an int as the second parameter. You can convert a number to a `QString` using the static function `QString::number`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that somewhere you are creating an object without passing the correct parameters to the constructor.

For example if you have a class SomeClass with a constructor like this

```
SomaClass(Qstring s1)
```

you cannot create a SomeClass like this;

```
SomaClass t;
```

You have to create instead:

```
SomeClasst t("text");
```